# Doctrine2 Filter Parameter empty value twig extensions

Tags: symfony, twig, twig-extension

In my application a company has their own subdomain. Im listening to kernel request event and setting the Company Filter(Doctrine Filter) parameter based on the company matching the subdomain.

```
    public function setCompanyFilter($companyId)
    {
        /** @var EntityManager $entityManager */
        $entityManager = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getManager();
        $filters = $entityManager->getFilters();

        $companyFilter = $filters->isEnabled('company_filter')
            ? $filters->getFilter('company_filter')
            : $filters->enable('company_filter');

        $companyFilter->setParameter('company', $companyId);

    }
```

The issue im having is that on twig extensions(filter/functions) the parameter is not setted. If i set the value before execute a filter/function everything works as expected.

Is there any way to execute some code before every twig filter/function/tag? Like listening to an twig event? Or how can i solve this issue without calling the setCompanyFilter on every twig filter/function/tag.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not set the custom value in the same event (i.e. `kernel.request`) that you are already listening to?

I assume you are using a custom [twig extension](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html#create-the-extension-class). If not extend the filter/function you are already using and do the same:

```
<?php

// src/AppBundle/Twig/AppExtension.php
namespace AppBundle\Twig;

class AppExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    private $customParameter;

    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('price', array($this, 'priceFilter')),
        );
    }

    public function priceFilter($number, $decimals = 0, $decPoint = '.', $thousandsSep = ',')
    {
        $price = number_format($number, $decimals, $decPoint, $thousandsSep);
        $price = '$'.$price;

        return $price;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'app_extension';
    }

    public function setCustomParameter($parameter)
    {
        $this->customParameter = $parameter;
    }
}
```

Inject the twig extension into your current listener and then call the method `setCustomParameter`, inject your custom parameter for use later in the request lifecycle, and then just call the filter/function as your normally would in your existing twig template.

Comment: Im think you did not understand my question. I have a twig function, for example called getXXX() that performs a query on the database and applies a doctrine filter(in this case the company id to the where clause). However, even if i set the filter parameter on the kernel_request it seems that on twig scope the value is not available/persisted and the company id parameter is empty. I Could on my function set the parameter value again, but this would need that i do it for every filter/function. The purpose of doctrine filters is create a general filter that filters all my queries.